# H2 embedded DB LIMIT + OFFSET> Integer.MAX_VALUE causes wrong result

Tags: sql, h2

I get weird behavior from using H2 SQL queries. Using Java8, spring-jdbc:4.3.13, h2:1.4.199, on Ubuntu Linux.

**Update: Confirmed this is a bug, check answer**

I have a PERSON table like this:

```
id | name
1  | "John"
2  | "Jane"
3  | "Frank"
```

When I run this prepared statement:

```
-- (Note ordering is descending.)
SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

- OK using: (`Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0`), I get all 3 rows: `[(3, Frank), (2, Jane), (1, John)]`
- OK using: (`20, 2`), I get row `(1, John)`.
- OK using: (`Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2, 2`), I get `(1, John)`
- NOT OK using: (`Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, 2`), I get `(3, Frank)`

So offset is working normally unless I use a very high number for limit, in which case I have no idea what's going on.

Same if I try other variants like "LIMIT ?, ?" (and switching the values).

So is this a bug, or a know limitation of H2/JDBC?

The same happens when I hardcode the values:

```
SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2147483646 OFFSET 2
```

The java code is a bit involved using spring-jdbc and rowmappers, so I cannot easily paste it here.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it might be a bug. Do you get the desired results if you use `-1` for the LIMIT instead of the very large positive integer values?

Comment: negative limit give the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Reported and confirmed at https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/2025

> This issue is caused by overflow in SortOrder.sort(ArrayList, int, int).
>
> The workaround is to avoid generation of FETCH, LIMIT, or TOP clause when limit is not needed.